# Número onde não deve aparecer

Tags: php

Sou iniciante em PHP e preciso de uma pequena ajuda.

Estou fazendo um sistema bem besta que realiza a soma de dois números, com isso, quando o usuário não digita nada o correto e informar a ele que precisa ser digitado dois número para se calcular a soma, eu consegui fazer isso, porém fica aparecendo um 0 na frente da mensagem, reparem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(0);
    if($_POST){
        $num1 = $_POST ['campo1'];
        $num2 = $_POST ['campo2'];
        echo $num1 + $num2;

        if($num1 <= 0 && $num2 <= 0) {
            echo "Numero invalido!";
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu código, você deveria verificar se **um ou o outro** número é menor ou igual a `0`, e não **os dois**. O `if` com o operador `&&` só será satisfeito se as duas condições forem válidas, enquanto que o operador `||` irá validar ou uma ou outra. Então você coloca o resultado da soma num `else`, caso uma ou outra condição não atenda ao critério:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
if($_POST){
   $num1 = $_POST ['campo1'];
   $num2 = $_POST ['campo2'];

   if($num1 <= 0 || $num2 <= 0) {
      echo "Número inválido!";
   }else{
      echo $num1 + $num2;
   }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda jovem, entendi totalmente sua lógica referente aos operadores. Após inserir sobre um else na estrutura correta funcionou perfeitamente.

Tks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na linha 6 `echo $num1 + $num2;`, você manda ele imprimir a soma de `$num1` + `$num2` e, em seguida, manda imprimir Número inválido...

Comment: Oi, obrigado por tentar sanar minha dúvida, fico grato!

Estou tentando entender o seu conceito, porém para mim não fez lógica pois eu solicitei a impressão do Número Inválido de $num1 <= 0 && $num2 <= 0, entende o que quero dizer..